# Exterior measure of total variation measure

Tags: measure-theory, total-variation, signed-measures

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a signed measure space.

If $\mu^*$ denotes the exterior measure of $\mu$ and $\Lambda_{\mu^*}$ denotes the set of $\mu^*$ measurables sets, i'm trying to find a relation between the sets $\Lambda_{{\mu^+}^*}$ and $\Lambda_{{\mu^-}^*}$, where $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^{-}$ and $|\mu|$ is the total variation.

I think that $$\Lambda_{{\mu^+}^*} \cap \Lambda_{{\mu^-}^*} = \Lambda_{{|\mu|}^*}$$
Is it true?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't every $\mu^+$-measurable set $\mu^-$-null, thus $\mu^-$-measurable and vice versa?

Comment: But you need that $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite